# How to find all substrings that match a pattern in Rebol

Tags: regex, rebol

Here, I'm attempting to find all matches of a pattern in a string:

```
theString: "There is a blue truck and a red car next to an orange building."
thePattern: [["blue" | "red" | "orange"] ["truck" | "car" | "building"]]
print parse thePattern theString
```

Instead of returning`["red truck" "blue car" "orange building"]`, the `parse` function returns `false`.

Does Rebol have any functions that can be used to find all matches of a pattern in a string, similar to the regular expression matching functions of other programming languages?

Comment: side note: Because Rebol is case-insensitive as far as word lookup is concerned *(though it is case-preserving in the word values themselves)*, it's rare that people use case switches like `theString`.  A lot of hyphenation, so `the-string` is what's done.  Most importantly, it keeps your code [Rebmu-compatible](http://rebmu.hostilefork.com).  :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try this:

```
string: "There is a blue truck and a red car next to an orange building."
pattern: [
    ["blue" | "red" | "orange"] 
    space
    ["truck" | "car" | "building"]
]

parse string [
    some [
        copy value pattern (print value)
    |   skip    
    ]
]
```

which prints:

```
blue truck
red car
orange building
```

`skip` is used to move to next character when the pattern is not matched. Also space is added to the pattern as it's not "bluetruck" or "redcar".

Parenthesis are used to execute Rebol code inside parse rules, so you can replace `print` with something else there (like `append block value` etc.)

Answer (score 3):

The [red](/questions/tagged/red) language already improves on Rebol's Parse in this regard:

```
parse "There is a blue truck and a red car next to an orange building." [
    collect [
        some [
            keep [
                ["blue" | "red" | "orange"]
                " "
                ["truck" | "car" | "building"]
            ]
            | skip
        ]
    ]
]

== ["blue truck" "red car" "orange building"]
```

Though not quite ready for primetime, Red is already hinting at progress beyond Rebol's current feature set.

Answer (score 2):

> Does Rebol have any functions that can be used to find all matches of a pattern in a string, similar to the regular expression matching functions of other programming languages?

Good answers already.  I'll point out that you can iteratively use FIND if what you want is a series position of where an exact match starts, without extracting it:

```
foo: "The quick brown quick jumped over the lazy quick"
while [foo: find foo "quick"] [
   print foo
   foo: next foo
]
```

You'll get:

```
quick brown quick jumped over the lazy quick
quick jumped over the lazy quick
quick
```

As another insight into PARSE's generality, I'll reiterate that the reason you're getting FALSE back is because your match rule says:

```
[["blue" | "red" | "orange"] ["truck" | "car" | "building"]]
```

There's no repetition primitive (such as SOME or ANY) and it's missing any way to skip over things.  So that would only match a single isolated string that would look like `bluetruck` or `redcar` or `orangebuilding`.  It basically expects a direct sequence of something out of the first set followed by something out of the the second set.

The specific operational model of parse is that there is a "parse position" which is started at the beginning of the series, and it is moved (or not) by how the rules are matched.  If the end of the rule matching happens and the parse position is at the end of the input series, then it returns TRUE.  If the rule applications complete and you're not at the end, you get FALSE.

Through a mixture of ordinary Rebol code (embedded with parentheses) and saving/setting the parse position using set-words or get-words, you can do pretty much anything.

```
theString: "There is a blue truck and a red ugly car next to an orangebuilding." 
theResult: copy []
thePattern: [
    any [
        to ["blue" | "red" | "orange"]
        start:
        thru ["truck" | "car" | "building"]
        finish:
        (
            append theResult copy/part start finish
        )
     ]
]
parse theString thePattern
probe theResult
```

That would get you:

```
["blue truck" "red ugly car" "orangebuilding"]
```

It's nice when you can solve your problem without needing to break into code like that--and often you can.  But good to have the option when you need it.

Note also that there is a `space` defined for the character literal, I prefer it in code to seeing `" "`...which can be disruptive as to understanding if you have to look backward to find the beginning of a string and forward to find the end of another one.  Worth the extra two characters!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this works so only with Rebol3. With Rebol2 this is more complicated.

```
theString: "There is a blue truck and a red car next to an orange building."

thePattern: [
  copy color   ["blue" | "red" | "orange"] 
   #" "
  copy item  ["truck" | "car" | "building"] 
]

collect [parse/all theString [
  some [ thePattern (keep rejoin [color " " item])  |   skip ]   
] ]
```

gives

```
== ["blue truck" "red car" "orange building"]
```